# Email not sending - core_email_queue not in the database

Tags: email, email-queue

Sorry guys I am a bit of a newbe ... But I am facing a problem with sending mails (order confirmation, Invoice, ect ...).

My cron job works fine according to my log but  core_email_queue_recipients and  core_email_queue havn't been created to queue all the emails.

I don't really get how this works but I followed all the steps correctly while I installed Magento but still having the problem.

Is anyone could helpme on that one  ?

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: What version of magento are you using?

Comment: Have you fixed it in the meantime? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Same issue in Magento 2.

Answer (score 1):

So as I understand, the tables are present, but there are no entries?

In the current 1.9.x version of MAgento, not all Mails are stored in those tables. Some of them are still sent directly.

Start over by placing an order, and re-validate you database.

If the tables are not created, check out the [magento database repair tool](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool). It compares two databases (original and possibly corrupted one) and creates missing table or rows.

cheers